# What does this setting do when copying SSIS packages? "Duplicate package folder structure on destination for selected packages"

Tags: ssis, ssms

What does this setting do for copying SSIS packages? "Duplicate package folder structure on destination for selected packages." Is there any reason why I wouldn't want to duplicate the folder structure?

[image: Copy Database SSIS Package Settings]